# Azure Event Hub - Process data through scala script

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have a requirement to send data present in a flat file from VM unix server to Azure event hub and to publish to azure blob storage.

I am able to do this using below code

```
val producer: EventHubProducerClient = new EventHubClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName).buildProducerClient
val batch: EventDataBatch = producer.createBatch()

Reading the content of my file line by line and sending to tryAdd methos. 
for (line <- fileContent.getLines)
{
batch.tryAdd(new EventData(fileLine)) }

// send the batch of events to the event hub
//producer.send(batch)

// close the producer
producer.close()
```

My file has got about 1000 records. For it Event hub has created about 12 requests (Seems this is doing randomly).

I am just trying to understand on what basis event hub creates the requests and is there a way I can control it?

Any info around it would be very helpful

Comment: Might be off-topic but what is the reasoning of using an event hub to transfer a file to blob storage? It seems way over complicated imho.

Answer (score 1):

Each publish operation to the Event Hubs service is limited to a certain number of bytes, governed by the tier of the Event Hubs namespace.  The quotas for each tier can be seen in the [Event Hubs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quota).

Each event that you add to a batch is measured against that limit when `tryAdd` is called.
If the event cannot safely fit into the batch, `tryAdd` returns `false`.  At this point the batch may be completely full or there may be some capacity left.  Any remaining capacity wasn't adequate to accommodate the full size of the specific event that was passed.

In addition to the size of the payload, your `fileLine` in this case, there is also some size overhead for diagnostics metadata and batch packaging that impacts the final size of the event and capacity of the batch.  Depending on the consistency of size of your `fileLine` after it has been serialized for transport, you may see batches of uniform size or may see some variation in the number of events that can be fit into a single batch.

The number of `send` calls needed is directly proportional to the number of batches that were needed to hold each of your `fileLine` events.  One batch may be published per `send` call, as the traffic for that call is subject to the byte-size limit enforced by the service.

I realize that the snippet in your question may be for illustration only, but I do want to mention that you're ignoring the return from `tryAdd`, which I would strongly advise against.  The `tryAdd` call will not fail if the batch is full.  If you ignore the return value, when `false` is returned, you're likely to not realize that an event wasn't accepted into the batch.  That often leads to data loss, as the event isn't in the batch but the application believes that it is and moves on.